# 'openssl rsa -in' command in python

Tags: python, openssl

I am trying to generate public key from private key generated using python subprocess.run() where I store the private key in a variable, not in a file. I want to use the same buffer variable as input to openssl rsa command as input which it can use to generate the public key. I am not sure how to pass this buffer in python code-

```
#generating private key and keeping it in a variable
filedata = subprocess.run(['openssl', 'genrsa', '4096'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout
```

Now using that filedata in openssl rsa command, how to pass this in python command in os.system() or subprocess.run()

```
os.system("openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout > public.key")
```

Is it possible to pass private.key data from the variable which holds the data to openssl rsa? Here I am avoiding to store the private key contents in a file. That is why I am using the filedata variable.

thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a `-in` option, then `openssl rsa` by default reads from *stdin*. So using `subprocess.run`, you can provide `filedata` as input using a command very similar to the one you're using to generate the private key.

First, let's modify your private key generation so that we get bytes from `subprocess.run` instead of a string:

```
filedata = subprocess.run(
    ["openssl", "genrsa", "4096"],
    check=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
).stdout
```

We can then pass `filedata` as input to `openssl rsa -pubout ...`,
which in the absence of a `-in` option will read from *stdin* by
default:

```
subprocess.run(
    ["openssl", "rsa", "-pubout", "-out", "public.key"], input=filedata, check=True
)
```

Now you have the public key in file `public.key`. If you would rather
have the public key in a variable instead of in a file, you can remove
the `-out public.key` option, in which case the command is almost
identical to the first one:

```
pubkey = subprocess.run(
    ["openssl", "rsa", "-pubout"],
    input=filedata,
    check=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
).stdout
```